# Create your own wurfl exception

Tags: php, wurfl

I am using php wurfl 1.3.1 with cakephp - The following user agent is being picked up as a mobile browser which is incorrect.

It is on a windows 7 machine, the 64 bit version of IE has no problem but the 32 bit version redirects to mobile.

(32 bit)**[PROBLEM]**

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GetMiroToolbar 1.2; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)`

(64 bit)

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0)`

If you do have a fix for me, please also let me know the proper steps to making sure the server reads the new configs properly. Do I just clear the WURFL cache? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `web_browsers_patch.xml` I added the following line :

```
    <device user_agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GetMiroToolbar 1.2; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)"
        fall_back="msie" id="msie_8">
        <group id="product_info">
            <capability name="model_name" value="8.0" />
        </group>
    </device>
```